# How to write loose index scan query in sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

There is loose index scan recursive query in postgresql https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Loose_indexscan. I have similar query, which I need to write in sqlalchemy.

Postgresql query:

```
WITH RECURSIVE t AS (
   (SELECT events.events.payload ->> 'type' as type FROM events.events ORDER BY events.events.payload ->> 'type' LIMIT 1)  -- parentheses required
   UNION ALL
   SELECT (SELECT events.events.payload ->> 'type' as type FROM events.events WHERE events.events.payload ->> 'type' > t.type ORDER BY type LIMIT 1)
   FROM t
   WHERE t.type IS NOT NULL
   )
SELECT type FROM t WHERE type IS NOT NULL;
```

So far my best effort in sqlalchemy is:

```
        table = self._get_table(source)

        top_select = select(
            [table.c.payload[source.value.type_path].label("type")]
        ).order_by("type").limit(1)
        cte_select = top_select.cte("t", recursive=True)

        inner_select = select(
            [table.c.payload[source.value.type_path].label("type")]
        ).where(
            "type" > cte_select.c.type
        ).order_by("type").limit(1).alias()

        bottom_select = select([inner_select.c.type]).where(cte_select.c.type != None)

        recursive = cte_select.union_all(bottom_select)

        final_select = select([recursive.c.type]).where(recursive.c.type != None)
```

however the result is not executable in postgresql and looks like this:

```
WITH RECURSIVE t(type) AS (
    (SELECT events.events.payload -> % (payload_1) s AS type
     FROM events.events
     ORDER BY type
     LIMIT %(param_1)s)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT anon_1.type AS type
    FROM (SELECT events.events.payload -> % (payload_2) s AS type
          FROM events.events,
               t
          WHERE t.type < % (type_1) s
          ORDER BY type
          LIMIT %(param_2)s) AS anon_1,
         t
    WHERE t.type IS NOT NULL)
SELECT t.type
FROM t
WHERE t.type IS NOT NULL
```

Error I get is:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.InvalidRecursion) recursive reference to query "t" must not appear more than once
LINE 8:  LIMIT 1) AS anon_1, t 
                             ^

[SQL: WITH RECURSIVE t(type) AS 
((SELECT events.events.payload -> %(payload_1)s AS type 
FROM events.events ORDER BY type 
 LIMIT %(param_1)s) UNION ALL SELECT anon_1.type AS type 
FROM (SELECT events.events.payload -> %(payload_2)s AS type 
FROM events.events, t 
WHERE t.type < %(type_1)s ORDER BY type 
 LIMIT %(param_2)s) AS anon_1, t 
WHERE t.type IS NOT NULL)
 SELECT t.type 
FROM t 
WHERE t.type IS NOT NULL]
[parameters: {'payload_1': 'type', 'param_1': 1, 'payload_2': 'type', 'type_1': 'type', 'param_2': 1}]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/f405)
```

How can I write that `Select ( select` part? Is it even possible to do in sqlalchemy?

Comment: What's the reason for not using the SQL directly in SQLAlchemy instead?

Comment: I see, change `inner_select` from `alias()` to `as_scalar()`, or just don't add the call to `alias()` at all, and use the result itself as the column expression: `select([inner_select])`. If it does not correlate `cte_select` automatically, add `.correlate(cte_select)` to `inner_select`. `alias()` is for creating FROM-objects, i.e. selectables that go to FROM clause.

Comment: Thank you @IljaEverilä. `.as_scalar()` does the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Ilja suggested in comment, `as_scalar()` does the trick. The final code is following:

```py
    def _get_event_types(self, source) -> List[str]:
        table = self._get_table(source)

        top_select = select(
            [table.c.payload[source.value.type_path].astext.label("type")]
        ).order_by("type").limit(1)
        cte_select = top_select.cte("t", recursive=True)

        inner_select = select(
            [table.c.payload[source.value.type_path].astext.label("type")]
        ).where(
            table.c.payload[source.value.type_path].astext > cte_select.c.type
        ).order_by("type").limit(1).as_scalar()

        bottom_select = select([inner_select]).where(cte_select.c.type != None)

        recursive = cte_select.union_all(bottom_select)

        final_select = select([recursive.c.type]).where(recursive.c.type != None)

        return [row[0] for row in self.db.execute(final_select)]
```